# Recommendation on client side echo cancellations

Tags: audio, webrtc, voip, noise-reduction, speex

I am developing a MCU based voip service. I think the traditional way of doing MCU is, you have N audio mixers at server and every participant in the call receive a steam that does not have their own voice encoded.
Guess what I wish to do is, have only 1 audio mixer running at server and (on a broadcast kind model) send the final mixer audio to every participant (For scalability obviously).

Now this obviously creates a problem of hearing your own voice coming from speaker as MCU’s output stream.

I am wondering if there is any “client side echo cancellation” project that I can use to cancel the voice of user at desktop/mobile level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is to filter/subtract the own voice in the MCU. Doing this on the client side does not work.

Comment: Thanks. Was wondering seeing some proposals on Microsoft blogs. Guess it was just a theory to reverse and cancel your own sound.

Comment: "filter/subtract the own voice in the MCU" - Please let know any tools / libraries doing this?, I am currently using GStreamer and looking for similar solution as Hitesh asked above, Even on MCU side is fine